# Newbie having jQuery conflict issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox, conflict

First I would like to apologize if this issue I am having has been solved fifty-five million times already. Unfortunately, I could not find an answer here. Also, I am very green to the ways of jQuery, so forgive my ignorance on the subject.

I am using jQuery for 3 areas (not sure what term to use) - a scroll to function, a fancybox gallery and a "back to top" button. Any two of them work fine together, when I try to implement all three, I lose fancybox.

Here is the code from the head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<link href="js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    function filterPath(string) {
        return string
            .replace(/^\//,'')
            .replace(/(index|default).[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$/,'')
            .replace(/\/$/,'');
    }
    var locationPath = filterPath(location.pathname);
    var scrollElem = scrollableElement('html', 'body');
    // Any links with hash tags in them (can't do ^= because of fully qualified URL potential)
    $('a[href*=#]').each(function() {
        // Ensure it's a same-page link
        var thisPath = filterPath(this.pathname) || locationPath;
        if ( locationPath == thisPath
                && (location.hostname == this.hostname || !this.hostname)
                && this.hash.replace(/#/,'') ) {
            // Ensure target exists
            var $target = $(this.hash), target = this.hash;
            if (target) {
                // Find location of target
                var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
                $(this).click(function(event) {
                    // Prevent jump-down
                    event.preventDefault();
                    // Animate to target
                    $(scrollElem).animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 900, function() {
                        // Set hash in URL after animation successful
                        location.hash = target;
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    });

    // Use the first element that is "scrollable" (cross-browser fix?)
    function scrollableElement(els) {
        for (var i = 0, argLength = arguments.length; i <argLength; i++) {
            var el = arguments[i],
            $scrollElement = $(el);
            if ($scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0) {
                return el;
            } else {
                $scrollElement.scrollTop(1);
                var isScrollable = $scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0;
                $scrollElement.scrollTop(0);
                if (isScrollable) {
                    return el;
                }
            }
        }
        return [];
    }
});
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
        }
    });

    $('.scrollup').click(function(){
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
        return false;
    });

});
</script>
```

And from below the body tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    nextEffect  : 'fade',
    prevEffect  : 'fade',
    padding     : 0,
    margin      : [15, 15, 40, 15],
    afterLoad   : addLinks,
    beforeClose : removeLinks
});

function addLinks() {
    var list = $("#links");

    if (!list.length) {    
        list = $('<ul id="links">');

        for (var i = 0; i < this.group.length; i++) {
        $('<li data-index="' + i + '"><label></label></li>').click(function() {
            $.fancybox.jumpto( $(this).data('index'));}).appendTo( list );
        }

        list.appendTo( 'body' );
    }

    list.find('li').removeClass('active').eq( this.index ).addClass('active');
}

function removeLinks() {
    $("#links").remove();    
}
</script>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Have you tried jQuery.noConflict()?

Comment: When you post questions with this much code, it's generally considered good form to indent / codify so that it's easy to read....

Comment: SLaks I do not know what you mean by "console" but I just ran it through WC3 Validator and there are several syntax errors in the fancybox gallery html markup.

Suman - where would I place noConflict()? Within it's own <script> tag?

Forgive my stupidity.

Comment: Here is the error from WC3 Validator:

Bad value gallery for attribute rel on element a: The string gallery is not a registered keyword or absolute URL.

…ay.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img width="192" height="138" alt="YP S…

Syntax of link type valid for <a> and <area>:
    A whitespace-separated list of link types, with no duplicate keywords in the list. Each link type must be listed as allowed on <a> and <area> in the HTML specification, or must be listed as allowed on <a> and <area> on the Microformats wiki, or must be an absolute URL.

Comment: So, in cleaning up your indenting, one of the things that I found is there is a missing closing parenthesis.  Check this line:  `$('<li data-index="' + i + '"><label></label></li>').click(function() {` - two lines down, you close it with `}`, but you are missing the closing `)`.

Comment: Not sure how to solve that issue. :-(

Comment: Add a closing parenthesis.  Isn't this your code? Can't you edit it?  Change the line to read `]);`

Comment: $('<li data-index="' + i + '"><label></label></li>').click(function() { $.fancybox.jumpto( $(this).data('index'));}).appendTo( list );
        }
added ); after } - it did not work.

Comment: Sorry for posting the code incorrectly cale.

Answer (score 0):

too much info to put in a comment, so:

1. Use a debug console.  With Firefox (and with Chrome), you can open a javascript console, and see if there are any errors being thrown: [Read this article for Firefox Tools](http://www.howtogeek.com/105320/how-to-use-firefoxs-web-developer-tools/) - and be sure to check out the "Web Console" section.
2. Indent your code.  I've edited your question to reflect proper indenting.  Doing so reveals problems much easier.
3. Below is a portion of code that is going to throw a javascript error, which will stop **all** javascript from running on the page.

code :

```
function addLinks() {
    var list = $("#links");

    if (!list.length) {    
        list = $('<ul id="links">');

        for (var i = 0; i < this.group.length; i++) {
        $('<li data-index="' + i + '"><label></label></li>').click(function() {
            $.fancybox.jumpto( $(this).data('index'));}).appendTo( list );
        // Changed below to close the parenthesis for the .click function...
        });

        list.appendTo( 'body' );
    }

    list.find('li').removeClass('active').eq( this.index ).addClass('active');
}
```

Comment: The only error it states is this:
TypeError: $target.offset(...) is undefined
http://andrealynnwhitfield.com/#contact
Line 43

Comment: Error from Chrome:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined (index):43
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Comment: @oldbroad That's due to this line in your code: `if (target) {`, which should read `if ($target) {`

Comment: Just fixed that. 
This is a error found via inspect element from firefox:
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. jquery-latest.min.

Comment: @oldbroad That's just a notice, not an error that you need to worry about.

Comment: Then no noticeable errors were found. I'm sure that there is a solution but I'm too green to figure it out at the moment.

Comment: Dumb question for you Cale - Do I paste the code you posted above into my document? Please don't slap me.

Comment: @oldbroad - well, you really just need to *modify* the one line.  See the comment I put in the code - "Changed below to close..."? The line *after* that is the one I changed.  You should change that line in your code, which will fix that issue.

Comment: Hi Cale, 

Sadly that did not work. I lost fancybox and the scrollup still is not functioning. Hmmmm. This has been very educational for sure.

I am signed up for a jQuery Essential training course.

Thank you for all of your help.

Comment: I did finally to get everything to work. I used a different jQuery scroll plugin and placed all the scripts to the bottom of the page. Lesson learned.